# GPU model not recognized in Additional Drivers tab

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am looking to install Nvidia's proprietary drivers in order to be able to use CUDA for some Machine Learning.

But I am not able to select the proprietary driver option as the GPU model is not recognized in Software & Updates under the additional drivers tab:
[It only says Nvidia Corporation: Unknown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksS7y.png)

But if I lookup the GPU through a lspci command, it is detected correctly:
[It is indeed a GTX1660](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMlaO.png)

Does someone know why that is the case?

Comment: Have you already tried to install latest NVIDIA drivers from webpage (https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/150803/en-us)? If not, you can give it a try. Please store your data before trying something with the driver, I ruined several times my Linux installation. For ML my personal best practice is to start from a fresh install and try to get the NVIDIA driver running. After driver installation verify that NVIDIA is detected (with 'nvidia-smi'). Check installation instruction on NVIDIA webpage (http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/435.21/README/installdriver.html)

Comment: February 15 2019 — I think that GPU it's too new for Ubuntu. What version of Ubuntu do you use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

A manual install of the driver, indeed solved the issue. Well the GPU model still isn't recognized but I have a working and compatible driver. Thank you!